# Need help in querying HDFS from drill

Tags: apache, hadoop, hdfs, apache-drill

I have drill and zookeeper installed in my laptop. I started HDFS in my laptop and see that I can query the csv and json files in HDFS. Now I wanted to query the files located in another laptop. Hence I started hdfs in the other laptop and when I gave the select * query, it failed(though I can execute `show files` query without issues).

The error I am getting is there in the dropbox link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5bgyw4jetweczoj/drill.log?dl=0

Both the laptops running Ubuntu

Apache drill version : 1.1.0

**I have the following questions:**

1) Is it possible to run drill in a machine outside hadoop cluster and query the hdfs files in the cluster?

2) If yes, is there any need of additional configuration change?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to run drill in a machine outside the hadoop cluster and query the hdfs files in the cluster. Start the drill shell (sqlline) from the command line and specify the zookeeper quorum to connect. See [Using an Ad-Hoc Connection to Drill](http://drill.apache.org/docs/starting-drill-in-distributed-mode/#using-an-ad-hoc-connection-to-drill). You can also use SQuirrel to connect. [Configuration for Windows](https://drill.apache.org/docs/using-jdbc-with-squirrel-on-windows/) is similar to Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check that. Do you have any idea why I get the BlockMissingException? I tried to access the hdfs file via Namenode UI without any issues. Please refer the log in the dropbox link mentioned above.